# Square numbers and spectrums

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let the *spectrum* of a formula $\varphi$ be the set of positive integers $n$ such that $\varphi$ has a finite model whose cardinality is exactly $n$.

In a first-order language consisting of a unary predicate $P$ and unary function symbols $f$ and $g$ (besides the equality symbol $=$) can we find a formula $\varphi$ whose spectrum is the set of square numbers?

I have no idea how to approach this question, and what role the two functions might have in $\varphi$. It would be great if someone could clarify what the role of the two functions $f$ and $g$ might be in the formula $\varphi$.

---

*Edit*

I can see that, in a model $\mathfrak{M}_2$ whose domain is $D_2 =\{a,b\}$, and where $P^{\mathfrak{M}_2} \neq \emptyset$ and $P^{\mathfrak{M}_2} \subseteq \{a,b \}$, since $|P^{\mathfrak{M}_2} \times P^{\mathfrak{M}_2}|$ would then be at most 4, so that the there cannot be a bijection between $D_2$ and $P^{\mathfrak{M}_2} \times P^{\mathfrak{M}_2}$, since they differ in cardinality. The same would hold for $\mathfrak{M}_3$ whose domain is $D_3 =\{a,b, c\}$, and where $P^{\mathfrak{M}_3} \neq \emptyset$ and $P^{\mathfrak{M}_3} \subseteq \{a,b, c \}$. So for any model $\mathfrak{M}$ the required bijection can only occur if $|P^\mathfrak{M}| = \sqrt{|\mathfrak{M}|}$. Given a model $\mathfrak{M}$ with domain $D$, one way to obtain the desired bijection would be to have $\sqrt{n}$ elements of the domain $D$ satisfy $P^\mathfrak{M}$ (where $D$ has cardinality $n$) and map the $d \in P^\mathfrak{M}$ to pairs $(d, d)$, and the $e \not\in P^\mathfrak{M}$ to pairs $(e,f)$ or $(f,e)$, where $e \neq f$.

I can't see clearly how to ensure these constraints are met with a suitable formula of predicate logic in the language described in my question.

Comment: Think about how the set $X\times X$ comes equipped with the *projection maps* $p: (a,b)\mapsto a$ and $q: (a,b)\mapsto b$. This suggests a "two-sorted" structure $X\times X\sqcup X$ with two unary functions from the $X\times X$-part to the $X$-part; do you see how to "fold in" the $X$-part into the $X\times X$-part using a unary relation symbol?

Comment: When you say a two-sorted structure do you mean a structure in which one sort is the set of pairs $(a, b) \in X \times X$ and the other sort is the set of  'plain' individuals $a, b \in X$? Are you suggesting that $f$ and $g$ are then the projection maps $p$ and $q$? I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your suggestions? I am utterly at a loss to see any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be the conjunction of the following sentences:

1. $\forall z\,P(f(z))\land P(g(z))$
2. $\forall z\forall z'\,((f(z) = f(z')\land g(z) = g(z'))\rightarrow z = z')$
3. $\forall x\forall y\,((P(x)\land P(y))\rightarrow \exists z\,(f(z) = x\land g(z) = y))$

Suppose $M\models \varphi$ is a finite model. Then:

1. says $f$ and $g$ are both functions $M\to P$. Together, they induce a function $h\colon M\to P^2$, given by $h(z) = (f(z),g(z))$.
2. says $h$ is injective.
3. says $h$ is surjective.

It follows that $|M| = |P^2| = |P|^2$, which is a square number. This shows that the spectrum of $\varphi$ is contained in the set of square numbers.

Conversely, let $m = p^2$ be a square number. Note that $p\leq m$. We define a model $M$ with domain $\{0,\dots,m-1\}$ by setting $P = \{0,\dots,p-1\}$. For any $z\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}$, let $f(z)$ be the quotient of $m$ when divided by $p$, and let $g(z)$ be the remainder (so $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are the unique natural numbers less than $p$ such that $z = pf(z)+g(z)$). Then $M\models \varphi$, so every square number is in the spectrum of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $L$ be a language with a predicate $P$ and two unary functions $f_1,f_2$. Find an $L$-sentence $\varphi$ whose models are structures $M$ such that there is a bijection between $M$ and $P(M)^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $P(M)^2$?

Comment: The set of pairs of elements of $P(M)$.

Comment: If $f_1$ is the first projection and $f_2$ the second projection, what about $\forall x(f(x) = f(y) \land g(x) = g(y) \leftrightarrow (P(f(x)) \leftrightarrow P(f(y)) \land (P(g(x)) \leftrightarrow P(g(y)))) \land \forall z(P(f(z)) \land P(g(z)))$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant the first part to express, but it does not really make sense. Since $P(f(z))$ and $P(g(z))$ holds for each $z$, the right hand side is vacuously true. Thus, your sentence says that $f,g$ are both constant and each has a value in $P$.

Comment: It's not clear to me why a formula true in structures in which there is a bijection between $M$ and $P(M)^2$ would capture the required spectrum. Perhaps if that were clearer it might be easier to see what was going on.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should think how many elements $P(M)^2$ would have...

Comment: In the case $M_1 = \{a\}$, and $P(M) = \{ a\}$, $P(M_1)^2 = \{(a,a) \}$ and I can see how a bijection would be constructed. In the case $M_4 = \{a,b, c, d\}$, and $P(M_4) = \{ a, b\}$, $P(M_4)^2 = \{ (a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}$ and so we can construct a bijection associating $a$ with $(a,a)$, $b$ with $(b,b)$, $c$ with $(a,b)$ and $d$ with $(b,a)$, then for $M_9 = \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i\}$ we could follow the same procedure with $P(M_9) = \{a,b,c\}$. Is that the idea behind the construction?

Comment: Where $f, g$ are the projection functions how about $\forall x,y ( P(x) \leftrightarrow f(x,y) = g(x,y) )$, so that elements in $P$ are a subset of the diagonal and elements outside of it are not.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Oops, I just wrote an answer exactly along the lines of your hint (but with the details filled in). I admire the patience of you, Noah, and tomasz in providing hints - but based on the OP's response, I thought they could benefit from seeing a complete solution.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I very much agree a complete solution is in order here! haha the reason I wrote out something smaller is that I'm writing from my phone :-)